# Why not access the AO-91 satellite at night during eclipse?

Tags: satellites

According to amsat-uk.org, the [AO 91 satellite should not be accessed during eclipse](https://wiki.amsat-uk.org/index.php?title=Beginners_Guide_to_LEO_Satellites#SATELLITES) because it is near EOL.

> - AO-91 (RadFxSat / Fox-1B) Near end of life. If you find it on, do not attempt to access in eclipse! (That is, don't use it at night)

I'm happy to play by the rules, but I'm curious: What about it getting old precludes it from use in the dark?

Comment: I'm guessing due to its **batteries'** age specifically? So when it's in sunlight it's still powered fine but at night its backup power no longer has the original capacity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In all likelihood the batteries on AO-91 are exhausted.  So contact during eclipse could POSSIBLY (at this time probably a very small possibility) cause the batteries to short and not allow any contact even during daylight.
Also the telemetry beacon probably has battery information which gives somewhat accurate information about the status of the satellite itself.

Found some telemetry info here from AmSat 
https://www.amsat.org/tlm/health.php?id=2&port=
 It's just a snapshot of the latest telemetry data, but I'm sure over time you can see the condition of the battery(or batteries) and how they've degraded.